# Python void/null function

Tags: python, function, void

Python noob so I might be going about this the wrong way

I want to use a try/except block to find if a value in a dict isn't set like

```
try:
    if entry['VALUE1'] == None: void()
    if entry['VALUE2'] == None: void()
except KeyError:
    print "Values not Found"
```

Of course the 'void' function doesn't exist, is there anything I can do to get round this so that code will work properly

Comment: It's not clear from this question, but maybe what you're looking for is a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?  Whenever you access an entry that doesn't exist, it's automatically added with a default value, so you don't have to worry when doing things like `entry['VALUE1'] += value`.

Comment: Just as a side note, its nicer to do `if entry['VALUE1'] is None:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try replacing `void()` with `pass`.

Of course, in practice, you can just do `if key in some_dict:`. But if you ever need a "do nothing" in a block, `pass` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if "VALUE1" in entry:
    foo()
```

to determine if the `"VALUE1"` string is in the set of keys of the `entry` dict.

Your logic would probably look something like:

```
if "VALUE1" not in entry or "VALUE2" not in entry:
    print "Values not found"
```

The `try` block is completely unnecessary for this test.

Answer (score 0):

```
if entry.has_key('VALUE1'):
 do_something()
```

or

```
if 'VALUE1' in entry:
 do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a function to help you out:

```
contains_all_keys = lambda d, keys: reduce(lambda a, b: a and b, map(lambda k: k in d, keys))
di = {'a':'some val', 'b':'some other val'}
if contains_all_keys(di, ['a', 'b']):
    print 'a and b present'
if not contains_all_keys(di, ['a', 'b', 'c']):
    print 'missing keys'
```

Comment: I think both "all(key in di for key in ['a','b'])" and "set(['a','b']).issubset(di)" are clearer than a nested triple lambda with a map and a reduce.

Comment: hah I think you're absolutely right.  I didn't know about all(), thats quite nice with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to evoke the exception, through a key lookup, the `if` is not neccesary.  It's sufficient to just express the lookup on a line by itself, such as:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['value']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'value'
>>>
```